# Send data by href (html) and get it with request function (django)

Tags: html, django, templates, request, href

I have a html page where I looping on model fields.

Html is:

```
{% for problem in problems_list %}
<p>
    {{ problem.id }} - {{ problem.incident_date }} - {{ problem.incident_specs }} -
    {{ problem.incident_location }} - {{ problem.incident_reason }}
    {% for action in actions_list %}
        {% if action.action_incident_id_id  == problem.id %}
            <form method="post">
                <input hidden name='problem_id' value="{{ problem.id }} ">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                href="{% url 'ex_action' %}"> Button </a>
<!--    action="{% url 'ex_action' %}"-->
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</p>

{% endfor %}
```

And here is a ex_action function:

```
def ex_action(request):
    return render(request, 'problems/ex_action.html', {'actions_list': actions_list})
```

It works well, but I need to pass a problem.id from for loop into ex_action, and I don't know how to do it.

I tried some constructions like `href="{% url 'ex_action'?=problem_id=problem.id %}"` and get it by something like `request.GET.get('problem_id')` or request.GET['problem_id'], but got TemplateSyntaxError on html, none as result on django code or MultiValueDictKeyError.
Read a lot of docs\issues, and find what people use ajax\js to solve it, but I don't know how.
Please help.

Comment: You forgot to set the `action` attribut of your `<form>` tag.